# Get reverse model foreign key object for inherited object

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have the following model with a reference an object and an object it inherits from:

```
class Employee(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)  
    entity = models.ForeignKey('companies.Entity', blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.OneToOneField('companies.Brand', related_name='brand', blank=True, null=True)

class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, db_index=True) 

class Brand(Entity):  
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

The problem is when I try to reference the inverse relationship, I can't access the Brand only the Entity.  I want to get the employee associated with a brand.  I tried this:

```
brands = Brand.objects.filter(pk=2)

for b in brands:
    print b.employee_set.all().query
```

It outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `employee`.`entity_id` = 2
```

I want it to output:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `employee`.`brand_id` = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your model file, the way you define Entity and Brand is called Multi-table inheritance, django will  automatically create OneToOneField relationship between entity and brand, but in your employee model, entity is your foreignkey but brand has onetoonefield with you employee model, that's not going to work. You can override the field by declaring your own OneToOneField with parent_link=True on Entity so there aren't oneToOneField relationship between entity and brand, check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance. Hope this help you.